# How can I calculate the impact on collision probability when truncating a hash?

Tags: hash, md5, probability, collision

I'd like to reduce an MD5 digest from 32 characters down to, ideally closer to 16. I'll be using this as a database key to retrieve a set of (public) user-defined parameters. I'm expecting the number of unique "IDs" to eventually exceed 10,000. Collisions are undesirable but not the end of the world.

I'd like to understand the viability of a naive truncation of the MD5 digest to achieve a shorter key. But I'm having trouble digging up a formula that I can understand (given I have a limited Math background), let alone use to determine the impact on collision probability that truncating the hash would have.

The shorter the better, within reason. I feel there must be a simple formula, but I'd rather have a definitive answer than do my own guesswork cobbled together from bits and pieces I have read around the web.

Comment: Keep in mind that you can also shorten a hash quite a bit by changing the base 16 hash to a larger base. For example, base 62 (upper, lower and numbers) brings a md5 hash string from 32 down to like 21 or 22 characters.

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan I had actually read that and tried a little test using an online base62 encoder, but the result was always a few characters *longer* than the original hash. e.g.: https://base62.io/ but maybe they're just not doing it right?

Comment: You need to specify an input base of 16 which is what a hash is. If you don't, it is likely using all standard ascii characters and decreasing the base from 256 -> 62 instead of increasing the base from 16 -> 62. Increasing the base is what will save you the characters. [Here is the one I used](https://www.dcode.fr/base-n-convert) when testing which allows you to set an input and output base.

Comment: Great thing about this is that you can use it without decreasing the collision/uniqueness/precision of a md5 hash. You could even use your own base converter (there are tons of userland implementations) and use additional symbols increasing your base even more and get down to the target 15 or so characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the chance of collisions with this formula:

```
chance of collision = 1 - e^(-n^2 / (2 * d))
```

Where `n` is the number of messages, `d` is the number of possibilities, and `e` is the constant `e` (2.718281828...).

Comment: Let's see if i got this right: if I have, say, 10,000 IDs that I want to generate, and let's say I truncate my hexadecimal hash down to 8 characters, the equation becomes: `1 - e^(-10000^2 / (2 * 16^8))` =~ 0.01157403..` or roughly 1.1% chance of collision?

Answer (score 2):

[@mypetition's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51622297/467386) is great.

I found a few other equations that are more-or-less accurate and/or simplified [here](http://preshing.com/20110504/hash-collision-probabilities/), along with a great explanation and a handy comparison of real-world probabilities:

- 1−e^((−k(k−1))/2N) - [sample plot here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%201%20-%20e%5E((-k%20*%20(k-1))%2F(2%20*%2016%5E12))%20for%20k%20%3D%201%20to%2050000)
- (k(k-1))/2N - [sample plot here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20(k%20*%20(k-1))%2F(2%20*%2016%5E12))%20for%20k%20%3D%201%20to%2050000)
- k^2/2N - [sample plot here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20k%5E2%2F(2%20*%2016%20%5E%2012)%20for%20k%20%3D%201%20to%2050000)

...where `k` is the number of ID's you'll be generating (the "messages") and `N` is the largest number that can be produced by the hash digest or the largest number that your truncated hexadecimal number could represent (technically + 1, to account for 0).

---

### A bit more about "N"

If your original hash is, for example, "38BF05A71DDFB28A504AFB083C29D037" (32 hex chars), and you truncate it down to, say, 12 hex chars (e.g.: "38BF05A71DDF"), the largest number you could produce in hexadecimal is "0xFFFFFFFFFFFF" (281474976710655 - which is 16^12-1 (or 256^6 if you prefer to think in terms of bytes). But since "0" itself counts as one of the numbers you could theoretically produce, you add back that 1, which leaves you simply with 16^12.

So you can think of `N` as 16 ^ (numberOfHexDigits).